How to Find the Subspace of  B Excluded from  Q-Image and Kernel?
Let A, B, and C be three vector spaces, and consider a map Q that takes vectors from
A to vectors in B, and from B to vectors in C. One could think this map as a matrix acts on vectors in A and B. A and B are in general of different dimension, Q are different matrixes with different dimensions.
I am interested in finding the subspace of B that is neither in the image of Q acting on A, nor capable of generating any vectors in C under the action of Q.
Is there a standard algorithm/command to deal with this question?

Don't cut and paste from a PDF. That's why the title has repeated letters. Please use MathJax.
